# What's the fastes query to look for the existance of certain rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm just wondering what's the fastest way to look up if at least one row, sharing certain attributes with other rows, does exist.

I'm not quiet sure how I should use SQLite here. Other DBMs have optimizers etc.. Do I need to code in a special way for SQLite? And, has LIMIT any impact here?

Many thanks in advance.
HJW

Comment: This question *severely* needs an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Found it. I need to use "SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (compley query)" to get highest performance. Tried several other ways but they were slower.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that SQLite is an embedded database does not imply that it cannot have a query optimizer ! [see here for an overview of SQlite query optimizer](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

in short, SQLite will behave the same as any other DBMS regarding the way it treats a query...

now, you are running on android, so your processing power may be a bit restricted. you should take care to avoid some kind of queries, to avoid wasting processor time or memory. queries resulting in the sorting of rows are notable to be slow, especially when there is no index defined on the sort key.